# Show an array with ngFor separated by type

Tags: angular

I am trying to show an array using `*ngFor` but I can not figure out how to show it in the way I want. For example, the next array:

```
[BMW, Apple, Mercedes, LG, Banana, iPhone]
```

Is an a array of objects so I use a Pipe to filter the array by a `type` property and in this case I have `Car Type`, `Food Type` and `Mobile Type`. The array ordered would be:

```
[BMW, Mercedes, Apple, Banana, iPhone, LG]
```

Well, my problem is that I want to show in this way:

```
CARS:

-BMW
-Mercedes

FOOD

-Apple
-Banana

MOBILE

-iPhone
-LG
```

Using this template:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items | orderPipe" >
    <div *nfIf="item.type == 'Car'>
        <h3>Cars</h3>
        {{ item.name }}
    </div>
</div>
```

But what I get is:

```
CARS  
-BMW
CARS
-Mercedes

FOOD
-Apple
FOOD
-Banana

MOBILE
-iPhone
MOBILE
-LG
```

Comment: Share the exact array of objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your array is already ordered by type as you showed, just add an`*ngIf` around the header:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items | orderPipe; let i=index"" >
    <h3 *ngIf="i==0 || items[i-1].type!=items[i].type">{{item.type}}</h3>
        {{ item.name }}
    </div>
</div>
```

This will print the header on the first iteration,`i==0`, and each time the type changes -- `items[i-1].type != items[i].type`.

Comment: `<h3 *ngIf="i==0 || items[i-1].type!=items[i].type">{{item.type}}</h3>`

It really works, thank you!.

Comment: @dperezac Glad it helped. Thanks for the correction. I've added it to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably want to transform your array into a nested array.

```
let transformedArray = [{
  type: 'Cars',
  items: ['BMW', 'Mercedes'],
},{
  type: 'Food',
  items: ['Apple', 'Banana'],
},{
  type: 'Mobile',
  items: ['iPhone', 'LG']
}];
```

Then use nested ngFors

```
<div *ngFor="let outer of transformedArray">
    {{outer.type}}:
    <div *ngFor="let inner of outer.items>
        -{{inner}}
    </div>
</div>
```

So ultimately you could do the sorting when you are transforming the array as opposed to in a pipe.